# Can't set headers after they are sent on express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean

I khow like a common question here on. But I couldn't get a solution from everywhere. 
here is my code: if row is not empty then render code page, otherwise perform another action.

```
app.get('/send',function(req,res){
  var code=req.query['c']; // -- get request from input
  connection.query("use mynum");
  var strQuery = "select * from table WHERE code='"+code+"' LIMIT 1";   
  connection.query( strQuery, function(err, rows){
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }else{
      if(rows.length==1){
        res.render('pages/code', {code : rows[0].code});
        connection.end();
        res.end();
      }else {
        // here is some actions
      }
    }
  });
  res.end();
});
```

the stack trace:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:690:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\wamp\www\vin_number\node_modules\express\lib\re
sponse.js:666:10)
at ServerResponse.res.contentType.res.type (C:\wamp\www\vin_number\node_modu
les\express\lib\response.js:532:15)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\wamp\www\vin_number\node_modules\express\lib\resp
onse.js:121:14)
at fn (C:\wamp\www\vin_number\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:900:10)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\wamp\www\vin_number\node_modules\
ejs\lib\ejs.js:323:3)
at View.render (C:\wamp\www\vin_number\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:93:8
)
at EventEmitter.app.render (C:\wamp\www\vin_number\node_modules\express\lib\
application.js:530:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\wamp\www\vin_number\node_modules\express\li
b\response.js:904:7)
at Query._callback (C:\wamp\www\vin_number\server.js:102:6)
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the problem you're running into / the errors you're getting? "Can't set headers after they are sent on express," but it seems like they only get sent in one of two scenarios, and if `rows.length !== 1` you should be able to write headers. Can you include that part of the code, as you may be writing the headers incorrectly

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're sending a response twice via `res.end()`. Get rid of the second one and you should be fine. Also, calling `res.end()` after `res.render()` is redundant since `res.render()` automatically ends the response with the rendered result by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just learned this! pass your responses through a function that checks if the response was already sent:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  var _send = res.send;
  var sent = false;
  res.send = function(data){
    if(sent) return;
    _send.bind(res)(data);
    sent = true;
};
  next();
});
```